# c - Getting a 'double' variable from inside a DialogProc Callback function

Tags: c, windows

I'm building a Windows application in C using Visual Studio and I need to set values for external variables from inside a DialogProc Callback function.

For string variables, I am using strcpy, and this works. However, I'm stuck when it comes to variables of type 'double'. Would anyone please be able to suggest a suitable method? And perhaps a better alternative to strcpy (for strings)?

I'm assigning the variable `expName` from a textbox as follows:

```
GetDlgItemTextA(hwnd, IDC_EDIT1, expName, 100);
```

and then copying that to a struct outside of my callback function using `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(myExperiment[free].name, expName);
```

I originally tried `myExperiment[free].name = expName;` but when the function ended `expName` did not exist anymore so I couldn't access that value.

Using `strcpy` when the function ends I can still access whatever `expName` was, however if the input is a double, I'm not sure how I can do this. This is what I tried (for a different struct):

```
double flowrate = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_EDIT3, NULL, FALSE);
memcpy(&myParameters[0][0].flowrate, &flowrate, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: are you asking how to set double typed variables?

Comment: Just *assign* to the variable? It don't really see the problem. How do you get access to the "strings"? Can't you use the same method to pass the `double` variables? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Edit the question to show the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Added code - let me know if that's sufficient

Comment: There's no point using `memcpy` if both `myParameters[0][0].flowrate` and `flowrate` have type `double`.

Comment: @aschepler is there any other way I could copy the value of 'flowrate' out of the function then?

Comment: Just assign it.  `myParameters[0][0].flowrate = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_EDIT3, NULL, FALSE);`

Comment: Yet assigning it like that doesn't let me write the value to a text file from outside of that function. I'm using `fprintf(f, "Flowrate is %d\n", myParameters[0][0].flowrate);` outside of the callback function to print `flowrate` to a text file. If `flowrate` was 56 for example, using `assert(myParameters[0][0].flowrate == 56);` confirms that it's 56 but when I use the fprintf function to print it to file it gives me 0 instead. That's why I had to use strcpy for strings. Any idea to get around that @aschepler?